# iOS send request directly to APNS without server

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

On Android, to send a notification all you need to know is GCM id of a device you want to notify. Assuming my user knows the id of another user, he sends a message directly to GCM server, what decreases  the load on my server. I don't have experience building iOS apps, so I want to know if the same approach is possible for iOS devices. If my user knows id of another apple device, can he send a request directly to APNS?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question, check the answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427500/can-we-send-push-notification-to-apns-from-ios-device  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215510/send-push-notification-from-ios-app

Answer (score 0):

Sending a push is just a matter of posting data to apple servers.

You can do it from your server or the device. It's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for response. One more question: can an android device post a data on an apple server? Is there some kind of signature check or something?

Comment: @Valera thats not directly possible, you will need your server in between the 2 platforms.

Comment: why not? please explain

Answer (score 0):

Try [NWPusher](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher). It contains an iOS demo application that shows how to send push notifications from iOS to iOS.