# Is it possible to send push notification from one iOS app to another iOS app?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am not very familiar with push notifications. But is it possible to send push notification from one app to another? I know you need a server to send notifications but is it possible implement that in an app.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate question, check the answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215510/send-push-notification-from-ios-app and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427500/can-we-send-push-notification-to-apns-from-ios-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No, pushes are sent from a server to a server.

Long answer: Of course, it's not common practice, but lots of fun.

To send out a push notification to an Apple device, you will need to connect with the APNS server and then send your notification in data format. Although this is usually done from a server, it can just as well be done from an iPhone or iPad.

If you want to get going yourself, I recommend reading all the documentation Apple provides on this topic ([start here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html)). Everything you need to know is in there, but you will need to pay attention to the details in order to get this to work.

An easier way to get going is by using [NWPusher](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher). This is an iOS framework that provides all the tools you need to push from iOS to iOS. It even includes an iOS demo app that does this:

- [NWPusher - Push from iOS](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher#push-from-ios)

Just a small warning: In order to push from iOS, you will need to include the push certificate and private key in the app bundle. This is *not* a secure place to keep such a private key and you definitely don't want your app's push certificate to leak.

Enjoy!