# iOS push notification iOS (device to device)

Tags: ios

I did push notification using APNS and provider but i don't want to use the provider instead i need to do provider work in iOS itself Is it possible to send and receive the push notification from device to device (without using provider)?

Comment: What problem you face in doing this? Or you have not try anything? Have you search in Google for it or Just come and Ask here?

Comment: i searched how to send the notification using APNS and provider  and i  can able to send / receive  the push notification from my app , APNS and provider ... i trying to do with out using provider ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I guess you always need a server in order to trigger the push notification**. You can't directly initiate the push message from iOS app to APNS.

In case you are using third party provider for sending message to APNS and want to get rid of it, you can write a web service in your own server which will communicate with APNS to send a push notification to your iOS app.

Comment: thanks for valuable  reply .... what if happens the web service  code which is used to trigger the push notification ... the same type of code is able to write in iOS ?

Comment: @ Rashmi Ranjan mallick It is possible. Sending notification just require a secure connection to APNS server. See one nice implementation here: https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher

Comment: i got the answer ...so we need to use web service or third party SDK (like pusher) as the provider without these two scenarios we can't able to send the push notification  ?

Comment: @CRDave: Ok. So, it's possible. This's kind of you are trying to imitate the server. But, one important point is, is it as secured as using a separate web service for connecting to APNS?

Comment: Yes because we are using same certificate and HTTPS connection.

Comment: @ Sabarish Jaganathan Pusher is not service. it is a code to send push notification. Read its Readme page properly to understant it.

Comment: ok what are the steps we need to follow without using provider or third party SDK ?

Comment: @CRDave: I got your point. But, still I think that having the messaging service outside of the app will give you more control in some contexts.

Comment: @CRDave: Why don't you post your points in a separate answer so that everyone understands clearly.

Comment: @ Rashmi Ranjan mallick yes i think that is good idea ... @CRDave just post the points alone or reference link ...we don't need code ....

Comment: The reason I am not giving answer is that this is Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427500/can-we-send-push-notification-to-apns-from-ios-device, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215510/send-push-notification-from-ios-app, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311306/ios-send-request-directly-to-apns-without-server

Comment: Second reason is I have never code for it But I know NWPusher  is working.

Comment: i tried NWPusher it is in progress..... my question is NWPusher library files are in objective c files type (.m and .h) is it work when we bridge objective - c file in swift project ? i mean library file itself ?